# Tkinter drawing triangle with three input length

Tags: tkinter, canvas, drawing, draw, triangle

I want to draw triangle by input length. So I made three entry that I can input data. But it says
"TypeError: buttonclick1() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', and 'c'"
Can you help me?

I want to make a triangle by three input length from tkinter canvas. Please help me!!

```
from tkinter import*


root=Tk()
root.title("도형 그리기")


def buttonclick1(a, b, c):
    a=ent_a.get()
    a=int(a)
    b=ent_b.get()
    b=int(b)
    c=ent_c.get()
    c=int(c)
    A = (0, 0)
    B = (c, 0)
    hc = (2 * (a**2*b**2 + b**2*c**2 + c**2*a**2) - (a**4 + b**4 + c**4))**0.5 / (2.*c)
    dx = (b**2 - hc**2)**0.5
    if abs((c - dx)**2 + hc**2 - a**2) > 0.01: dx = -dx
    C = (dx, hc)

    coords = [int((x + 1) * 75) for x in A+B+C]

    cv.create_polygon(*coords)
    
               

lb1=Label(root, text="1.삼각형 그리기")
lb2=Label(root, text="삼각형 세 변의 길이를 입력하세요")


ent_a=Entry(root, width=20)
ent_b=Entry(root, width=20)
ent_c=Entry(root, width=20)

bt1=Button(root, text="삼각형 그리기", command=buttonclick1)

cv=Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, bg="white")

lb1.grid(row=0, column=0)
lb2.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
ent_a.grid(row=2, column=0)
ent_b.grid(row=2, column=1)
ent_c.grid(row=2, column=2)
bt1.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)


cv.grid(row=12, column=0, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `buttonclick1` function has 3 parameters which are not being passed to it(a, b, c) but when I read your code there is no need for those parameters so you can  change `buttonclick1(a, b, c)` to `buttonclick1()` in line 8 and it will work without any errors.